# php msql sort values by name

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling a bit with the new mysql/php code, I have a sniplet which picks out all my books, but I would like to sort it by the author. (`row[1]`)

```
$db=new mysqli("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass");
$db->select_db("$dbname");
$query="select * from book";
$result=$db->query($query);
//find number of rows
$num_rows=$result->num_rows;    

for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++)
{
    //fetch  row
    $row=$result->fetch_row();
    $total=$total+$row[2];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='http://isbndb.com/search/all?query=".$row[8]."'>$row[4]</td>" ; 
    echo "<td>$row[1]</td>" ;
    echo "<td>$row[10]</td>" ;
    echo "<td>$row[9]</td>" ;
    $stoke=$row[2]-$row[3];
    $tstoke=$tstoke+$stoke;
    $tout=$total-$tstoke;
    echo "<td width=\"30\">$stoke</td>" ;
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

how does one do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this in your query after your `select`

```
$query="select * from book ORDER BY author";
//or
$query="select * from book ORDER BY author DESC";
```

**Avoid using * try mentioning the field names** (i.e.)

```
$query="select id,books,author,etc from book ORDER BY author";
```

further reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Comment: `ORDER BY` is 2 words.

Answer (score 0):

$query="select * from `tablename` order by `coloumnname` ASC or DESC";
 where you can choose your condition ASC or DESc